# How to implement password protected PDF file in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone

Is any one have an idea to how to implement a password protected PDF file in iphone sdk. I mean to I need to create a password pdf file from my application.Please help me.

Any one's help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the same problem

I've solved the problem using a little trick... that is, generate a PDF and put into a "password protected" zip file

I've using the zip library [ziparchive](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/) that allow protection

Hope this help

Comment: when u extract zipfile(created by zip library ziparchive) in PC what happen its ask for password?

Comment: Usually yes ... depends on ZIP client application. In my case i used the application itself to expand archive

Answer (score 4):

Here's another solution that might be better for your purposes:

CGPDFContextCreate takes a dictionary in which you can pass a password as one of the attributes.

The details for CGPDFContxtCreate you'll find in Apple's reference documents at:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPDFContextCreate

And the password setting information you'll find in Apple's docs here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Auxiliary_Dictionary_Keys

Comment: both link broken. please help

Answer (score 1):

We can provide Password for PDF file by using:

```
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"owner", kCGPDFContextOwnerPassword, @"user", kCGPDFContextUserPassword, kCFBooleanFalse, kCGPDFContextAllowsCopying, kCFBooleanFalse, kCGPDFContextAllowsPrinting,  nil];
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/samplePDF.pdf", NSHomeDirectory()];
        if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:fileName]) {
            [fileManager createFileAtPath:fileName contents:nil attributes:nil];
        }

        // Create the PDF context using the default page size of 612 x 792.
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(fileName, CGRectZero, dictionary);
```